# Rails - Delete rows from a non indexed table

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails

I have a connection table that connects between 2 tables. It has 2 columns: user_id and course_id. The name of the table is: course_sub_managers. This table does not have an index. So, how do I delete all rows that meet a condition in which course_id = certain variable? As for now I use:

```
sql = "DELETE FROM course_sub_managers WHERE course_id = " + @course.id.to_s
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(sql)
```

Is there a Rails way to write it?

Comment: Why not just grab the course and delete through the association?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you have an course model where you have written something like:

```
has_many :course_sub_managers
has_many :users, through => :course_sub_managers
```

in that case you can use:

```
@course.course_sub_managers.delete_all
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds you just want to handle the deletion of a course? Use the :dependent => :destroy on your relationships.

```
has_many :course_sub_managers, :dependent => :destroy
```

It will automatically remove the related table items when you destroy a course.